# How to check range in checkedlistbox c# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a checkeboxlist with 100 items. Obviously user can check items one by one as many as he need, but I would like to give to user option check range of items (let's say with Shift hold button). So, user check one of the items (let's say item index 5) and then press and hold shift button and check next item (index 10), so I range of the items should be checked from 5...10

I have not found anything about such implementation, looks like it doesn't exist and no one did such kind of things.

How to do it?

Comment: You can remember the last item user clicked, when the user clicks another item and Shift key has been pressed then there's your range.

Comment: I find 100 items in a CheckBox List a little too much. Perhaps you could add autocompletion and tokenize string like "5-10". But the whole question looks like it  fall into a library recommendation thingy.

Comment: An other way will be to turn this check box into a collapsable gird. As grid may have a better support for multiple selection, and range.

Comment: You could load your items to a `ListView` or `DataGridView` control, which already implements the functionality you're describing. You will have to wire the selection event of your item to update the `Checked` state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep track of your last index:

```
int lastIndex = -1;
```

In your form's constructor, wire things up:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();

  checkedListBox1.CheckOnClick = true;
  checkedListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += CheckedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
  checkedListBox1.MouseDown += CheckedListBox1_MouseDown;
}
```

And then use these methods to change the items in the range:

```
private void CheckedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  lastIndex = checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex;
}

private void CheckedListBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift) {
    var useIndex = Math.Max(lastIndex, 0);
    var x = checkedListBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
    if (x > -1 && x != useIndex) {
      if (useIndex > x) {
        for (int i = useIndex - 1; i > x; i--) {
          checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, !checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i));
        }
      } else {
        for (int i = useIndex + 1; i < x; i++) {
          checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, !checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```